# TypeScript send event type to get the target.id

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to send the click event on an element but TypeScript does not like `any` and gives out a warning, so I am trying `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` but then it throws an error.

```
`Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`
```

```
const closeWindow = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => { 
  if (e.target.id === 'modal-window') ...
}

return (
  <div id='modal-window' onClick={closeWindow}>
    <div id='modal-content'>...</div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks that's true still gives out an error, I am amending the question

Comment: Huh, that surprises me (but I can replicate it). I'm sure we *just* had this question. I think the "solution" was a type assertion (blech)...

Comment: It's really weird cause if I log `e.target` I do get `<div id="modal-window" ...`

Comment: Setting it to any would be bad anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `e.target` could be just about anything, because it's the innermost target of the event, not necessarily the element on which you set the event handler.

The element you hooked the event on is `currentTarget`, it works correctly:

```
const closeWindow = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => { 
    if (e.currentTarget.id === 'modal-window') {
        console.log("Match");
    }
};
```

*(Or you could use `HTMLDivElement` to be more specific.)*

The reason is that if you clicked the `span` here:

```
<div onClick={handler}>
    <span>Click me</span>
</div>
```

`e.target` would be the `span`, not the `div`. `e.currentTarget` is the `div`.

---

You've said you need to use `e.target` because you're using that to determine whether the click was on `modal-window` or `modal-content`. Although you could use a type assertion (they're both `div` elements), if you're differentiating between them anyway, perhaps have two handlers, one for each:

```
return (
    <div id='modal-window' onClick={closeModalWindow}>
        <div id='modal-content' onClick={closeModalContent}>...</div>
    </div>
);
```

Then you wouldn't need the `id` values (unless you use them for something else) and the component would be reusable.

If you want clicks on `modal-content` to not trigger your handler, for instance:

```typescript
return (
    <div onClick={closeWindow}>
        <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>...</div>
    </div>
);
```

...then `closeWindow` doesn't need to use an `if`.

Comment: @Álvaro - I've figured it out, and I feel a bit silly now. Let me fix it.

Comment: The problem is that I am relying  on the propagation to determine if it is the `modal-window`  or the `modal-content` that has been clicked

Comment: @Álvaro - Different handlers perhaps? Or the same handler, but on both elements?

Comment: `modal-window` takes the entire screen as an absolute div, when clicked I want to close, but `modal-content` is a little div inside that I don't want it to react to the click event

Comment: @Álvaro - If you want to prevent clicks on `modal-content` from bubbling to `modal-window`, you can attach a handler to `modal-content` that prevents bubbling, thus preventing the `modal-window` handler from being called. Or assign `pointer-events: none` in the CSS (but that has knock-on effects that may not be desirable).

Comment: Ah... you got it, the `e.stopPropagation()` did it, I was an idiot and was doing `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Álvaro - It's an easy mistake to make, we all have. :-)